# how to create vuejs unsplash pagination?

Tags: api, vue.js

I am trying to create gallery unspalash API with vuejs.

I done most of the part but stack in pagination. I see there is a link that give me all page info but it is in string format

```
<https://api.unsplash.com/photos?order_by=popular&page=1&per_page=4>; rel="first", <https://api.unsplash.com/photos?order_by=popular&page=1&per_page=4>; rel="prev", <https://api.unsplash.com/photos?order_by=popular&page=45021&per_page=4>; rel="last", <https://api.unsplash.com/photos?order_by=popular&page=3&per_page=4>; rel="next"
```

the data is in string format. how i show it in vue pagination; i have no idea.

I need 4 boutton First, Next, Previous, Last from this string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any body want to help?

Answer (score 0):

ok i find the Solution.
this.pagination = response.headers.link.split(", ");
so it will create array from the string. now you can loop that array and find single link from this with rel=name

```
<span class="red" v-for="pagi in pagination" v-bind:key="pagi.id">
      <button
        v-if="pagi.includes('first')"
        class="bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 text-gray-800 font-semibold py-2 px-4 border border-gray-400 rounded shadow mr-3"
        v-on:click="fetchPaginateNews(pagi.split('; ')[0])"
      >First</button>
      <button
        v-if="pagi.includes('next')"
        class="bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 text-gray-800 font-semibold py-2 px-4 border border-gray-400 rounded shadow mr-3"
        v-on:click="fetchPaginateNews(pagi.split('; ')[0])"
      >Next</button>
      <button
        v-if="pagi.includes('prev')"
        class="bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 text-gray-800 font-semibold py-2 px-4 border border-gray-400 rounded shadow mr-3"
        v-on:click="fetchPaginateNews(pagi.split('; ')[0])"
      >Prevous</button>
      <button
        v-if="pagi.includes('last')"
        class="bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 text-gray-800 font-semibold py-2 px-4 border border-gray-400 rounded shadow mr-3"
        v-on:click="fetchPaginateNews(pagi.split('; ')[0])"
      >Last</button>
```